# File Not Found Error when trying to read csv file in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to open a csv file and Jupyter keeps throwing errors. I am using the full path and still no luck. GA.csv is the name of the file and it is saved to my desktop.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/Users⁩/⁨nicholasgoodman/Desktop/GA.csv")
```

When I run this, I get the error message below. I've tried moving the file, I'm sure this is the correct directory, and this method for opening the file has worked in the past for me.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File 
b'/users\xe2\x81\xa9/\xe2\x81\xa8nicholasgoodman/desktop/GA.csv' 
does not exist: 
b'/users\xe2\x81\xa9/\xe2\x81\xa8nicholasgoodman/desktop/GA.csv'
```

Comment: Try to use the raw string like `df = pd.read_csv(r"/Users⁩/⁨nicholasgoodman/Desktop/GA.csv")`

Comment: I saw people recommending that in other threads, but that didn't work for me either

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on Windows? Then try this with your path.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/laman/Downloads/test.csv')
df.head(5)
```

I got the result.

```
    col1    col2
0   test1   test2
1   1111    2222
2   3333    4444
```

---

You may also try not to use absolute path but relative, depending on your Jupyter file locates.

```
df = pd.read_csv('../../Download/test.csv')
```

If you copy the path from somewhere, then just type it again. You could copy invisible characters that is not allowed in your path somehow.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on a mac

Comment: Have your path non-English characters?